# Invertibility of combinatorial matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

> Fix integers $n$ and $k$ with $0 \leq k < \dfrac{n}{2}$. Let $I$ be the set of all $k$-element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Consider the matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j\in I}$ where $a_{ij}=1$ if $i\cap j=\emptyset$ and $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise. What is the easiest way to see that $\det(A)\neq 0$?

For example, for $n = 3$ and $k = 1$, we have $\det(A) = 2$. More generally, for $k = 1$, we have $\det(A) = \pm (n-1)$ (since $A$ is the all-ones matrix minus the identity matrix).

Comment: can you predict closed form for determinant? if so, you can prove it with induction

Comment: For $k=1$ it should be $\pm (n-1)$. but in general I don't know.

Comment: ok, thanks anyways

Comment: how do you know the determinant is never 0?

Comment: I don't know, but I very much believe so.

Comment: for $k=1$, isn't the matrix just the identity and thus the determinant is $1$? where did you get $\pm (n-1)$ from?

Comment: no, it is the all-ones-matrix minus the identity.

Comment: for $k=2$, the eigenvalues for a given $n$ are ${n-2 \choose 2}$ occurring once, $-{n-1 \choose 3}$ occurring $n-1$ times, and $1$ occurring $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$. I assume you can prove that these are the eigenvalues by finding all the eigenvectors; then $0$ won't be an eigenvalue, so determinant will be nonzero. I presume this will extend to $k \ge 3$.

Comment: Your matrix is the adjacency matrix of the Kneser graph. See http://math.mit.edu/~csikvari/spectral_graph_theory_V3.5.pdf for its eigenvalues.

Comment: @darij grinberg Indeed (Theorem 2.8 page 10) ! Please, transform this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your matrix is the adjacency matrix of the Kneser graph $KG_{n, k}$ (using the notation from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph)). Its eigenvalues are known; here is a quote from the Wikipedia:

> For $j=0,\ldots,k$, the eigenvalue $\lambda_j=(-1)^j\dbinom{n-k-j}{k-j}$ occurs with multiplicity $\dbinom{n}{j}-\dbinom{n}{j-1}$ for $j > 0$ and $1$ for $j = 0$. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120323231232/http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2011-12/2term/ma192b/kneser-evals.pdf) paper for a proof.

This is also proved in

- Corollary 6.6.1 of [Chris Godsil, Karen Meagher, *Erdös–Ko–Rado Theorems: Algebraic Approaches*, Cambridge University Press 2016](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316414958).
- Theorem 1 of [Philipp Reinfeld, *Chromatic Polynomials and the Spectrum of the Kneser Graph*](http://www.cdam.lse.ac.uk/Reports/Files/cdam-2000-02.ps.gz) (freely available).

The oft-given reference to Godsil and Royle, *Algebraic Graph Theory* seems wrong: they only appear to prove the set of eigenvalues, not their multiplicities. (Although the multiplicities might follow from their argument, if there is a way to lift them through an equitable partition.)

Note that the words "with multiplicity $\dbinom{n}{j}-\dbinom{n}{j-1}$ for $j > 0$ and $1$ for $j = 0$" can be replaced by "with multiplicity $\dbinom{n}{j}-\dbinom{n}{j-1}$", since $\dbinom{n}{j}-\dbinom{n}{j-1}$ equals $0$ when $j = 0$.

As you know, the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues. Thus, the above formula for the eigenvalues yields that the determinant of your matrix is
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=0}^k \left(\left(-1\right)^j \dbinom{n-k-j}{k-j}\right)^{\dbinom{n}{j}-\dbinom{n}{j-1}} \neq 0
\end{align}
(since all $\dbinom{n-k-j}{k-j}$ are positive integers when $k \leq n/2$).

Answer (score 2):

**An idea only**

W.l.g. let all the elements of $I$ which contain $1$ come first when forming your matrix.

Then the matrix has the form $\begin{pmatrix}O&B \\B^T&D\\\end{pmatrix}$ and its determinant is 
$$|O-BD^{-1}B^T||D|=|BD^{-1}B^T||D|.$$
Since we can assume $D$ is invertible by induction, we require $|BD^{-1}B^T|$ to be non-zero.

Comment: I haven't though much about your idea yet, but the fact that it makes a simplification for $k=1$ is not good evidence that your idea is a good/useful one. I mean, I don't even know if it makes a simplication for $k=1$. For $k=1$, you just get 1-Id.

Comment: $BB^T$ is very simple for other examples.

Comment: do $k=2$ then ${}$

Comment: I don't agree with  $|O-BD^{-1}B^T||D|=|BB^T|$ : there is no reason explaining why $D$ could be cancelled.

Comment: @JeanMarie. I was thinking that $|BD^{-1}B^T|$ could be dealt with as if $B$ was a square matrix.

Comment: @JeanMarie. Is it possible for $BB^T$ to be non-singular when $BD^{−1}B^T$ is singular?

Comment: Take $B=\begin{pmatrix}1& 0\end{pmatrix}$ (line vector) and  $D=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\1& 2\end{pmatrix}$; you will see that the product $\det(B D^{-1}B^T)\det(D)$ is $2$ whereas $\det(BB^T)=1$.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. I suppose even simpler is  $BDB^T=O$.

Comment: @S. Dolan But the issue was $BD^{-1}B^T$...

Comment: @JeanMarie. Yes, but $D=(D^{-1})^{-1}$. An even simpler example would be $D=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\1& 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer : this isn't a solution**. It has to be considered as a hint complementing the indications provided by S. Dolan.

Let us write matrix $A$ under the form $A_{n,p}$.

Here is an example : the representation of $A_{10,2}$ (therefore with dimension $45 \times 45$) with a recursive structure of the form given by S. Dolan :

$$A_{n,p}=\begin{pmatrix}0&B\\B^T&A_{n-1,p}\end{pmatrix}$$

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Graphical representation of $A_{10,2}$ : zeros in dark blue ; ones in light blue.*

We remark a pretty block structure. Why do we have it ?

It is due to the fact that we have chosen to rank the different combinations (subsets with 2 elements) in **lexicographic order**, i.e :

$$\begin{array}{rr}
\color{red}{1}&2,\\       
\color{red}{1}&3,\\      
\color{red}{1}&4,\\      
\color{red}{1}&5,\\       
\color{red}{1} & 6, \\      
\color{red}{1}         &     7, \\      
\color{red}{1}         &     8, \\      
\color{red}{1}         &     9,  \\     
\color{red}{1}         &    10,\end{array} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\begin{array}{rr}     
       2         &     3, \\      
       2         &     4, \\      
       2         &     5, \\      
       2        &      6, \\      
       2         &     7, \\      
       2        &      8,  \\     
       2        &      9, \\       
       2        &     10, \end{array}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\begin{array}{rr}      
       3        &      4, \\      
       3        &      5,\\      
      \cdots & \cdots \\     
       7       &       8, \\      
       7        &      9, \\      
       7       &      10, \\      
       8        &      9, \\      
       8       &      10,  \\     
       9       &      10.
\end{array}$$

The first 9 subsets with 2 elements (indexing the first 9 lines and columns) all with common element "1", explain in particular why the $9 \times 9$ upper left block is zero, the next 8 subsets with 2 elements account for the diagonal block $8 \times 8$, etc.

Therefore it is not surprising that once we get rid of the first $10$ cases where figure $\color{red}{1}$ is present, we fall "recursively" into the previous case with only $9$ elements.

Remark : we shouldn't be surprized that the dimensions match : we have

$$1+2+3+\cdots + 9=\dfrac{9 \times (9+1)}{2}=45,$$

a particular case of $\sum_{k=1}^n k=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}.$

Now, let us change $p$ from $2$ to $3$, keeping $n=10$. We get the following matrix, which has still a different structure :

[image]

*Fig. 2 : (Art Nouveau ?) Matrix $A_{10,3}$ with the same color conventions as in Fig. 1. The diagonal block dimensions are $36 \times 36$, (where $36=\binom{9}{2}=\tfrac{9 \times 8}{2}$), $28 \times 28$, $21 \times 21$,...*

Related (for $2^n \times 2^n$ matrices) : [Determinant of matrix defined by set partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1728470), [Invertibility of Set Intersection Signed matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1940455), https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1361250